App Approved on Google Play but Not Accessible in Store - Invalid URL
I uploaded my app to Google Play and it got approved. After approval, I released the version to users. Although it says "Available on Google Play," my app is not accessible on the Google Play Store, and the provided URL is invalid. This has been going on for 1.5 days. Did I do something wrong? Note: The release option is active.
